# How can i pass a nested array in retrofit?

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

How to pass a nested array in **retrofit post request**. The array is to be like this :

`"bags": "[[7, 1], [8, 1], [9, 1]]"`

Tried List, Map also JsonObject and JsonArray but no luck.

I have to iterate a List of CarryBag class. Below is a CarryBag class and have to create a format like this "bags": "[[7, 1], [8, 1], [9, 1]]"` where first element is carryBagId and second element is purchased quantity.

```
  public class CarryBag {
        @SerializedName("carry_bag_id")
        private String carryBagId;
        @SerializedName("vendor_id")
        private String vendorId;
        @SerializedName("bag_name")
        private String bagName;
        @SerializedName("bag_size")
        private String bagSize;

        @SerializedName("status")
        private String status;
        @SerializedName("BAG_ID")
        private String bagId;
        @SerializedName("Name")
        private String name;
        @SerializedName("Price")
        private String price;
        @SerializedName("Qty")
        private int purchaseQty;
}
```

Comment: have you tried Gson  to transform it into string ?

Comment: No doesn't know how to use Gson.

Comment: check my answer it will work.

Comment: So simple 
you just add 

new Gson().toJosn(AnyObject)  it will return a string

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyBag{
  List<List<Integer>> bags;
}


String data = "{\"bags\":[[7, 1],[8, 1], [9, 1]]}";


Gson gson = new Gson();
MyBag bagList = gson.fromJson(firstData, MyBag.class);
```

**Pass bagList to retrofit**

Comment: First You have to create this "{\"bags\":[[7, 1],[8, 1], [9, 1]]}".how to build this "{\"bags\":[[7, 1],[8, 1], [9, 1]]}"

Answer (score 0):

Your json structure has embedded array. So try with the follwing code.

```
try {
                JSONArray bags = new JSONArray(jsonObj.getJSONArray("bags"));
                for (int i = 0; i < bags.length(); i++) {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = bags.getJSONArray(i);
                    for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "VALUES: ["+i+","+j+"]" +jsonArray.getInt(j));
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```